# How to display Xamarin date picker upon clicking a button in viewmodel

Tags: c#, xamarin

In my platform agnostic Xamarin project, in the page view model (MVVM approach used) I have a command with the following code:

```
        DateSelectionCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            DatePicker datePicker = new DatePicker();
            datePicker.IsEnabled = true;
            datePicker.IsVisible = true;
            datePicker.Focus();
        });
```

This approach advised on Xamarin forums and I expect that when I have clicked on the button connected to the `DateSelectionCommand` the datepicker should be displayed. **But it does not**.

I have set handler on `Focused` event for DatePicker, but it does not get noticed when I call `datePicker.Focus()`.

Is there a straightforward way to display Xamarin datepicker when I click on a button?

---

**UPDATE**

I've been advised to add datepicker to the page layout (thanks @sushihangover).

In case I am calling this code in viewmodel, that does not know about the page layout, is it possible to solve this task?

Comment: You are creating a datepicker but you are not adding it to your layout

Comment: @SushiHangover thank you, if I call this command in viewmodel, how can I add it to the layout in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could pass the **DatePicker** as **CommandParameter** to ViewModel

#### in xaml

```
<StackLayout VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">

        <Button  Text="OpenPicker" Command="{Binding DateSelectionCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference picker} ,Path=.}" HeightRequest="40" WidthRequest="200" />

        <DatePicker x:Name ="picker"  IsVisible="false" />

</StackLayout>
```

#### in code behind

```
DateSelectionCommand = new Command((arg)=> {

       var picker = arg as DatePicker;

       picker.IsEnabled = true;
       picker.IsVisible = true;
       picker.Focus();
              
            
});
```

Comment: @Rafael @Lucas Zhang, This breaks the MVVM architecture, the **ViewModel** must not know about the **View**. Lots of developers don't know they are breaking the MVVM design pattern, In order to show or hide `DatePicker` or any `VisualElement`, use binding in the `IsVisible`property, and set it to a boolean property in the ViewModel. Hence any change in the VM's boolean property will notify the View.

Comment: Another method would be to use EventHandler. Declare EventHandler in VM, define it in code behind (page.xaml.cs) then invoke it from the VM whenever required, this is useful when we have multiple actions when an element is shown or hidden. Reply to this if someone needs a separate answer.